# Plugin's required JS not being inserted in my theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, scripts

All my plugins and their necessary .js files aren't being inserted in my theme's head. The CSS files are being inserted ok, but not the .js files. Not sure what's wrong. When I switch to a default theme, it's fine.

I've got `<?php wp_head(); ?>` straight before `</head>`

AND

`<?php wp_footer(); ?>` straight before `</body>`

Comment: wp_head() should be called just before the ending tag of `</head>`, NOT `</header>`. And please add the complete code of the enqueue_scripts thing. Otherwise it's not possible to find the bug.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Sorry, how do I do that? And I meant `</head>` sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hey by using enqueue script to add all js and css file

```
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

Example here

```
 /**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' )
```

i am sure it work fine